# Is there a security benefit in knowing if my iPhone is jailbroken?

Tags: ios, iphone

There is an app for the iPhone supposedly detects if your smartphone has a jailbreak installed. Is there a security benefit in knowing whether your phone has a jailbreak or not?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Product recommendations are not on topic here, so I removed the part of the question asking for that. The rest of the question is good, though! If you dislike my edit, you can change it back to the original state. Thanks!

Comment: @Anders I don't think the question was about the app, but about the benefit. I edited to reflect my assumption.

Comment: thank you and you are correct in your assumptions of jailbreaks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## YES! It can tell you if someone has jailbroken your phone and gained control/ability to spy on you.

[This app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/system-and-security-info/id1080681261) detects the real sources of jail breaking just in case it's hidden.

If you jail broke your iPhone, then good for you you did it right. If not... something else insidious is going on. [See this answer on Apple SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/237762) for more information, but basically the application tries to detect things you can only do if jailbroken. It then notifies you if you are jailbroken or not. This can be useful for finding out if someone jailbroke your phone for nefarious reasons.

The real reason someone has to jailbreak YOUR iPhone is to spy on you. This gives them access to normally locked parts of your phone, the ability to copy text from your phone to their monitoring services, to hide their activity, and many other bad things.

If your iPhone is jailbroken and you did not do it, you have a compromised phone, **however this could be due to company contracts!** If it's a work phone this could be for making sure you aren't leaking company secrets through your phone, to prevent access to certain websites and services they don't want running on your phone, and many other legitimate reasons for *them*.

If it's not a work phone, but your personal phone it could be because your providers(whoever gave you the phone) is spying on you.

If it's your personal phone and you bought it you've been compromised big time and should start changing credentials from a secure terminal for all remote accounts and get a different phone.

To get rid of the jailbreak you can reinstall from iTunes to a factory image, which will overwrite the entire phone. This is a destructive process, but ensures the jailbreak is gone.

Answer (score 0):

The benefit to knowing your device status is understanding your threat landscape. The vast majority of security threats to iPhones are exclusive to jail broken devices so you [significantly increase your security risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking#Security.2C_privacy.2C_and_stability) in this state. Additionally it puts the device in an supported state so any security vulnerabilities are unlikely to be resolved, let alone found. The jail break itself violates the EULA too depending on your location.

As to using an app to determine this... You're unlikely to have accidentally done this yourself. It's possible that if you found, stole, or bought a used device from an individual they might have done this before the exchange. As Robert noted, it is also possible that anyone with motive and access to your device could jail break it.

Unless the app  comes from the official Apple App store, I'd be weary of what it actually is and what it will do on your phone. If it is jail broken, and this is not an official app, it could be malicious.

If you're concerned and want to ensure your device is not jail broken, you can simply [Restore the phone from iTunes](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-unjailbreak-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch/) and it will be put in a non-jail broken state. This is a great option if you are unsure of your device's status. You should also setup a good passcode, ideally alpha-numeric, and control access (physical and technical) to the device to protect it going forward.

Comment: Donw vote reasons: Jailbreaking is used often to install spy apps and the traces can be easily hidden.

Comment: @RobertMennell Yes, I was answering too generally. Updated with specific vulnerabilities and some extra info.

Comment: It's also possible that someone else closer has jailbroken the phone, such as friends and family or employer IT departments. Many people have a reason to jailbreak your phone. Some may be nefarious, some may be contractual, some may be bad friends and family. Also restoring a backup and reinstalling from itunes are two different things. one will remove jailbreaking, one will not.